# CSS Transition not happening on :hover but happening on :active

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a few SVGs I'm trying to animate.  When I hover or click the whole svg, the children should change colors.  This is all working.  I want to animate the color change on :hover and :active but am getting inconsistent results.  When the SVG is clicked, the animation runs, but doesn't on hover.  This seems strange to me.

```css
.fillStroke {
  fill: #007fa3;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.icon:hover .fillStroke {
  stroke: #007fa3;
}

.icon:active .fillStroke {
  fill: #333333;
  stroke: #333333
}
```

```html
    <svg id="Layer_1" class='icon' data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 14.85 15" height='auto' width='100px'>
    <title>icon</title>
    <g id="_Group_AttachS" data-name="&lt;Group&gt;AttachS">
    <path id="fillStroke" class="fillStroke" d="M5,15a4.54,4.54,0,0,1-1.17-.16A5.36,5.36,0,0,1,.14,11.22,3.85,3.85,0,0,1,1.23,7.39L7.33,1A3.18,3.18,0,0,1,12,1.06a3.14,3.14,0,0,1,.1,4.57L6.31,11.38a1.77,1.77,0,0,1-1.74.5,2.06,2.06,0,0,1-1.42-1.4,1.55,1.55,0,0,1,.42-1.54L8.29,4.13l.71.7L4.27,9.64a.55.55,0,0,0-.16.57,1.05,1.05,0,0,0,.71.69.77.77,0,0,0,.78-.24l5.75-5.75a2.12,2.12,0,0,0-.1-3.16A2.18,2.18,0,0,0,8,1.66L1.95,8.09A2.85,2.85,0,0,0,1.1,11a4.39,4.39,0,0,0,3,2.92,3.1,3.1,0,0,0,3.11-.82c3.14-3.14,6.87-6.76,6.91-6.8l.7.72s-3.76,3.65-6.9,6.79A4,4,0,0,1,5,15Z"/>
    </g>  
    </svg>
```

Here's a link to a codepen that makes what I'm trying to do pretty obvious.
https://codepen.io/cameronlewis35/pen/XgLxoP

Comment: It is working on hover for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't transition between a keyword property (like `none` on your CodePen) and a value property (like `#0016e4`).  If you want to use a keyword property that will translate, you can try `transparent` as that's functionally similar to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` and has clear steps between that and your target.

Example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgXzBW

Comment: Thank you kindly.  That'll do it